# How to move sliderfield bar as per the values enter in editfield in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I know how to fetch values from slider and put values into edit field but
i am not finding anything about moving slider field bar as per the values inserted in edit field?

I use following for getting values from slider field

```java
FieldChangeListener listenerslider1 = new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            try {

                if (field == mdrdageslider1) {
                    int ageslidervalue = mdrdageslider1.getValue();
                    String strageslidervalue = Integer
                            .toString(ageslidervalue);
                    edtmdrdage.setText(strageslidervalue);

                }

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

but not having any idea of moving scroll bar as per the edit field inserted values?

Answer (score 1):

I think I am missing something here.

I presume what you are calling a slider is the GaugeField in the API.  It offers the getValue() method that you have already using.  It also offers the setValue() method.  So in your EditField's changeListener, you can reference the field and use setValue() to update it.

I see you have a separate similar question, now solved:
[Issue while using moving effect on slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214592/issue-while-using-moving-effect-on-slider)