# Issue while using moving effect on slider

Tags: blackberry

Here i use a value changing effect on a slider; if i move the slider, it will scroll and display updated values in an edit field, as per the moving of the slider bar.  Also, there is an edit field effect where the slider should be moved as per the values entered into the edit field; but it is not working.

When i comment out part of the edit field effect, it is working properly but when i apply that edit field effect again, then it is not working ...

// for slider move

```java
    FieldChangeListener listenerslider1 = new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            try {

                if (field == serumosmslider) {

                    int serumosmslidervalue = serumosmslider.getValue();
                    String strplasmaslidervalue = Integer
                            .toString(serumosmslidervalue);
                    edtserumosm.setText(strplasmaslidervalue);

                }

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    serumosmslider.setChangeListener(listenerslider1);
```

// for  editfield

```java
    FieldChangeListener listenereditslider1 = new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

            hfmslider1.deleteAll();
            String stredtweight = edtserumosm.getText().toString();

            int editweight = Integer.parseInt(stredtweight);

                SliderField theSlider = new SliderField(slider2thumb,
                        slider2progress, slider2base, slider2thumbfoc,
                        slider2progressfoc, slider2basefoc, 201,
                        editweight, 10, 10);
                hfmslider1.add(theSlider);
                hfmslider1.invalidate();


        }

    };

    edtserumosm.setChangeListener(listenereditslider1);
```

Comment: SliderField is not a BB standard Field.  Where did you get that?  Does it have a 'setValue()' method that you can use?  Are you sure recreating it each time is good idea, because that remove the instance of the SliderField that you have the change listener associated with?

Comment: so what u suggest ? plz give me any solution for that

Comment: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Creating_a_slider_1626520_11.jsp from here i got sliderfield

Comment: Please can you explain this again "but it is not working when i comment the part of editfield effect it is working properly but when i apply that editfield effect again then it is not working".  What you have said doesn't make sense to me and I'd rather not guess what your problem is.

Comment: I have checked and the SliderField (see here: https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/component/SliderField.java) does have a setValue() method, and that will cause the Field to repaint.  So I suspect that is all you need in your EditField's FieldChangeListener.

Comment: after removing the edit field listener slider is moving properly but when i apply editfield listener it is not moving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be recreating your `SliderField` every time the `EditField`'s value changes.

```java
    SliderField theSlider = new SliderField(slider2thumb,
           slider2progress, slider2base, slider2thumbfoc,
           slider2progressfoc, slider2basefoc, 201,
           editweight, 10, 10);
    hfmslider1.add(theSlider);
```

I don't think you want to do that.  Just like you *update* the `EditField` text when the slider field changes, I think you should *update* the `SliderField` value when the `EditField` text is changed.  So, something like this:

```java
FieldChangeListener listenereditslider1 = new FieldChangeListener() {

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

        if (field == edtserumosm && context != FieldChangeListener.PROGRAMMATIC) {

            String stredtweight = edtserumosm.getText().toString();

            try {
                int editweight = Integer.parseInt(stredtweight);
                serumosmslider.setValue(editweight);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // TODO: anything?
            }
        }
    }

};

edtserumosm.setChangeListener(listenereditslider1);
```

Comment: it is not working its throwing exception error 104 stack overflow exception

Comment: it is throwing exception again when i am applying listener on slider field after removing slider field listener edit field listener is working

Comment: @Kirti, see the update to my code.  Make sure the test for `context != PROGRAMMATIC` is there.  That being missing probably caused the stack overflow.  Note:  you really should put that test in **both** listeners (slider field and edit field).

Comment: hay i want u r help in my previous question if is it ok with u can i contact u on u r mail id?

Comment: i don't provide free email support, no. please read my profile for more.